# understing Cook theorem and input length

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

Following is my understanding of Cook theorem.

> Let P be a $\mathcal{NP}$  problem.
>
> And let M be a polynomial NDTM for P,
>
> $$
> M(x) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> 1\text{ if x∈ P}\\
> 0\text{ otherwise}
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> By Cook theorem, there is a polynomial mapping R, such that
>
> R(M) = φ  where φ is a Boolean formula expression.
>
> And
>
> M(x)= 1       ⇔         φ (x') = true

My question is

1. My understanding is correct?
2. What't the relationship between x and x' ?
3. I am confused. M accept any length of input digit of x, but Boolean formula accept x only finite fixed input digit of value (x').  How can we connect M and φ  even though their input length is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $R$ should map strings $x \in \{0,1\}^{\ast}$ to Boolean expressions with the property that $M(x) =1 $ if and only if $R(x)$ is satisfiable. So rather than $R(M)$ maybe you should write $R(x)$. Then $R(x)$ is a Boolean expression and we can talk about its "truth value" $R(x)(y)$ on a particular string $y$, where $y$ is a choice of "$1=true$" or "$0=false$" for each of the variables appearing in $R(x)$.  Then we should have $M(x)=1$ if and only if there exists $y$ such that $R(x)(y) = true $. So $y$ is just the "certificate" for $R(x)$. It's length will depend on $x$ because as $x$ changes, the number of variables in $R(x)$ may change.  I hope I'm not adding to your confusion; if you had gotten any other feedback I would not have risked confusing you further with my limited knowledge of theoretical computer science.

Comment: Great! Thank you @Pliny the ill. You really helped me.

Comment: My pleasure. So I think the mistake you were making was in thinking that $R$ maps Turing machines to Boolean expressions. But what cook levin says is that for each NDPT Turing machine there exists a poly-time functions from inputs to Boolean expressions etc. So the function will depend on which NP problem you're reducing to "the satisfiability of Boolean expressions" and it will send input strings to Boolean expressions.

Comment: One more question. Let the NDTM be not polynomial machine. Still, is there map R ?  ( R doesn't need to be polynomial here)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the reduction $R$ needs to know how big to make the Boolean formula $R(x)$. $R(x)$ is a Boolean formula that codes the statement "$y$ is an accepting computation path *of length $p(|x|)$*  for $M$ on input $x$" (now thinking of y as a certificate for the language of strings accepted by M). Where $p$ is a polynomial representing the run time for $M$. It's the bound $p$ that allows you to code "M accepts x" as a finite object like a Boolean formula. and if you have a non polynomial bound on the run time, the reduction will not be a poly time reduction.

Comment: Again I'm far from an expert though, so definitely get a second opinion if you can. This is all coming from vague memories from a class I took as an undergrad

Comment: Thank you @Pliny-the-ill, I think that if M is an algorithm which is eventually halts, we can write down the R(x). I wish somebody would confirm this.

Comment: Yes I think you're right so long as there is a bound $b(|x|)$ on the run time which is computable. But in order to talk about NP completeness you have to talk about polynomial time reductions. It doesn't do any good to reduce one NP problem to another if the reduction is exponential or something because then you haven't really said anything about the relative hardness of the two problems.

Comment: The point of the cook levin theorem is that if you can solve "satisfiability of Boolean formulas" in poly time then you can solve "x is accepted by M" in poly time. If the map from strings x to Boolean formulas didn't run in polynomial time, then even if you had a poly time algorithm for "satisfiability..." you couldn't solve "x is accepted by M" in poly time because youd have to send x through an algorithm that doesn't run in poly time just to get something that can be checked in poly time. So the run time would be a polynomial plus a non polynomial which is not necessarily a polynomial.